# Ember form-for addon's text-field onblur not working

Tags: javascript, ember.js

**Using the latest Ember Version 3.11**

I tried onblur and focusOut, but focusOut throws error as it's a tagless component. None of them are working.

I'm trying to build a user form and validate the input when the user blur's from the field.

I'm using the below addon's together

- https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for
- https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset
- https://github.com/poteto/ember-changeset-validations

Component Template File

```
{{#form-for user submit=(action "submit") as |f|}}
  {{f.text-field "name" autocomplete="off" placeholder="enter name" onblur=(action "validateOnBlur")}}
  {{#if user.error.name}}
    <p>{{user.error.name.validation}}</p>
  {{/if}}
  {{f.email-field "email"}}
  {{#if user.error.email}}
    <p>{{user.error.email.validation}}</p>
  {{/if}}
  {{f.password-field "password" }}
  {{#if user.error.password}}
    <p>{{user.error.password.validation}}</p>
  {{/if}}
  {{f.submit "Create User"}}
{{/form-for}}
```

Component Javascript File

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { get }   from '@ember/object';
import Changeset from 'ember-changeset';
import lookupValidator from 'ember-changeset-validations';
import UserValidations from '../../validations/user';

export default Component.extend({
  init() {
    this._super(...arguments);
    this.user = new Changeset(get(this, 'model'), lookupValidator(UserValidations), UserValidations);
  },
  actions:{
    validateOnBlur(changeset, property){
      debugger
    },
    async submit(changeset){
      await changeset.validate();
      if(changeset.isValid){
        changeset.save();
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Validator

```
import {
  validatePresence,
  validateLength,
  validateFormat
} from 'ember-changeset-validations/validators';

export default {
  name: validatePresence(true),
  email: [
    validatePresence(true),
    validateFormat({ type: 'email' })
  ],
  password: [
    validatePresence(true),
    validateLength({ min: 8 })
  ]
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the cause why **onblur** is not getting triggered, as there is **no attribute** onblur in the **text-field.hbs**

https://github.com/martndemus/ember-form-for/blob/master/addon/templates/components/form-fields/text-field.hbs

The passed **onblur** from the **form** is not getting attached to it. I added **onblur=onblur** under **f.control** in the addon file(**text-field.hbs**) directly for checking and now it's working fine.